# Why pandas dataframe lost its decimal position when downloaded to csv and opened in excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas

**Background** - I have a pandas dataframe, that I want to save in csv, then further analyze in Microsoft Excel

Here's my pandas dataframe

```
percentile  avg             min          
96          109572.557673   104500.000000
100         351892.011122   193328.000000
```

My code is just basic like

`pd_read_csv(table.csv)'

When I save and this to excel the result become

[image]

How to download that with normal decimal place

Comment: What it the content of the exported file as text?

Comment: Its possible, but I don't know

Comment: This wasn't an open question ;) you should just show us the content of the file (as text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is most likely that Excel is set to use as decimal separator the character `,` while the pandas `to_csv()` function uses `.`. Try to modify the export line as this:

```
df.to_csv('file.csv', index=False, decimal=',')
```